# error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch

Tags: f#

Getting the error:

```
error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'Map<ContentAndYear,DemoMap>'    
is not compatible with type
    'seq<ContentAndYear * DemoMap>
```

Problematic Code: `Demo` is where the error is occurring.

```
type Demo = Map<ContentAndYear,DemoMap>

type ContentAndYear = Content * Year

let demoMap =
    dataMap
    |> Seq.ofList
    |> Seq.map(fun (content, data) ->
        { Content = content
          Year = data.Year
          Person = data.Person
          NullContent = nullContent.[content].contentraw
          PercentContent = nullContent.[content].contentraw
        })
    |> List.ofSeq

let demolist = 
    demoMap
    |> List.map (fun x -> (x.Content,x.Year) |> ContentAndYear,x)
    |> Map.ofList 

let x = demolist |> Demo  <---- Problem Line
```

How to Solve? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type `Demo` is not a new type, but an alias for `Map<ContentAndYear, DemoMap>`, so your last line is completely equivalent to this:

```
let x = demoList |> Map<ContentAndYear, DemoMap>
```

The type `Map<_,_>` has a constructor that takes a `seq<'key * 'value>`, but you're trying to pass a `Map<_,_>` to that constructor, so naturally, the compiler complains.

How to solve this depends on what you actually meant.

**Option 1**: if your definition of `Demo` is what you actually intended, then `demoMap` is already of type `Demo`, so you can drop `|> Demo` completely:

```
let x = demoMap
```

**Option 2**: if you intended the last line to compile as it is, then you probably meant for `Demo` to be its own type, not an alias. That is to say, you meant for it to have a constructor that takes `Map<ContentAndYear, DemoMap>`:

```
type Demo = Demo of Map<ContentAndYear, DemoMap>

...

let x = demoMap |> Demo
```